# clientX and clientY returns decimal value in IE on Zoom

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

MouseEvent clientX and clientY in javascript returns decimal values in IE when browser is zoomed in/out.

**Example:- X coords: 147.16000366210937, Y coords: 32.57999801635742**

One can check this behavior using this
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_mouse_clientxy

On 100% it returns Integer values.

Same if we do in other browser example Chrome or Firefox then it always returns integer values.

Because of this one of method is failing on server side. Since that method accepts integer values.

Off-course I can convert the coordinates by using **parseInt**.

But is there any reason of this behavior for IE? And any solution/settings for IE that might fix this apart from converting the values.

Since on other browser it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation than you can see the return value is **double floating point value**, as redefined by the CSSOM View Module. Originally, this property was defined as a long integer.

[image]

References:

(1) [MouseEvent.clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX#Return_value)

(2) [MouseEvent.clientY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY#Syntax)

To solve the issue, You can try to convert the value to INT in your code for IE browser.